# file security android: how can I make a file to be read by my android application only

Tags: android, encryption, filesystems, fuse

I have a set of encrypted files on my android device's sd card. My application reads the encrypted file using bufferedInputstream and generates the decrypted file in the application's internal storage. The application then reads the decrypted file(.pdf, .swf, .flv) to view it.
How can I make sure that a user (including root user on rooted devices) can not access the decrypted files?

1. can I remove the read/write rights of the decrypted file, as soon as
   my application opens it to read? if yes please guide me how?
2. can I delete the file from the internal storage as soon as my
   application opens it to read. If yes please guide me How?
3. I stumbled upon https://github.com/seth-hg/fuse-android. If
   nothing else works, is it a good idea to build a file system in user
   space to handle such cases? If you have tried it, please point me to
   right direction or a tutorial.

Comment: You can't. Overall you got an encrypted file and the key to decrypt it on the device at some point. The rest is just homework for someone interested. Especially on rooted devices.

Comment: @alextsc thanks for replying. What if i use fuse-android? How good/effective is this approach to solve this problem?

Comment: I never used that myself. But it won't change things much, just make it a bit more work for anyone who's interested in the files. As said you can't solve that. It's a principle, if you can decode encrypted data on the device, the device owner can get it if he wants. It's just a question of how much work he wants to put into that. You delete the file after decrypting? Take a memory snapshot. You got a key in your app? Extract that. And so on. Simply not feasible at all.

Answer (score 2):

Once the user gains root, you are not able to prevent access to any file. As the security of android is based (mainly) on permissions in file system.

What you can do is store the decrypted content in the memory and delete the file (or avoid creating it in first place)

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. But my concern with this approach is, what if the files are big? I have .flv and .swf files. Also, in order to run animation using .swf files I have to decrypt more than one .swf file. keeping all in memory might not be possible.